# XSLT - if first element of splitting by empty space > 0, show empty cell

Tags: xml, xslt

In my xml, the column where position()=3 can have these kind of values:

```
0.00 asg
0,34 dgfg
16.34 assfsf
334,77 sfsdf
```

So basicaly it has a float number with 2 decimals, an empty space and a string. WHat I need to do is this: if the number is 0 (so 0, 0.00 or 0,00) then show an empty cell. If it's larger than 0, don't change anything.

Here's what I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="cell[position()=3]" priority="7">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="newtext" select="concat(normalize-space($text), ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="perValue" select="substring-before($newtext, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="perInt" select='format-number($perValue, "#")'/>
    <id><xsl:value-of select="perInt" /></id>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="perInt='0'">
        <td style="border:1px solid #d6d6d6;">
          <div>
            ...
          </div>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

But it doesnt work. The value of the column is 0.00 sdfdf and it is shown. When the value is >0 it works, the correct value is shown.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a simpler way to solve this, but to fix yours you need to add a `$` character when you call a variable:

```
<xsl:value-of select="perInt" />
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$perInt" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:when test="perInt='0'">
```

should be:

```
<xsl:when test="$perInt='0'">
```

Note also that some of your values use a decimal point, and some a decimal comma. Hopefully, that's not true with your real input.

---

### Edit:

> If the input value is "0.00 asg", then the output should be "" (empty
>   string). If the number in the input is larger than 0, show the input.

Consider the following **input**:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <input>0.00 asg</input>
    <input>0.34 dgfg</input>
    <input>-16.34 assfsf</input>
    <input>334.77 sfsdf</input>
    <input>334,77 sfsdf</input>
</root>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="input"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:if test="number(substring-before(., ' '))">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <output/>
   <output>0.34 dgfg</output>
   <output>-16.34 assfsf</output>
   <output>334.77 sfsdf</output>
   <output/>
</root>
```

Note that the result for `<input>334,77 sfsdf</input>` is empty; that's because `number('334,77')` returns `Nan`.

If you change the second template to:

```
<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:if test="number(substring-before(., ' ')) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

then the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <output/>
   <output>0.34 dgfg</output>
   <output/>
   <output>334.77 sfsdf</output>
   <output/>
</root>
```

Comment: Now when the value is 0.00 items, the column is hidden. I need the column to be shown, just the value to be empty.

Comment: I am afraid I am not entirely with you. If the input value is "0.00 asg", then the output is   `<id>0</id><td/>`. If that's not what you want, you need to clarify (and I suggest you don't say things like "don't change anything", but say *exactly* what you want to see in each case).

Comment: If the input value is "0.00 asg", then the output should be "" (empty string). If the number in the input is larger than 0, show the input.

Comment: @petko_stankoski See if the edit to my post answers your question.